# Kendo-ui, Scheduler, timelineMonth view, error with workDayStart and workDayEnd

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

If configure kendoScheduler with:

```
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
      workDayStart: new Date(2013, 1, 1, 9),
      workDayEnd: new Date(2013, 1, 1, 17),
      ...
```

than timelineMonth view will thow exeption when open with "Show business hours" option.

Example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/UYeQI/2

1. Click "Show business hours"
2. Switch to "TimeLine Month" view

I made this example from Telerik demo
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline
just add workDayStart and workDayEnd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `workDayStart` and `workDayEnd` are related to `showWorkHours` you must **not** set them globally.

This is because the month view doesn't support work hours.

see: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-showWorkHours

> The **showWorkHours** option is supported when views.type is set to "day"
>   or "week".

For each view type for which you would like to use `workDayStart` and `workDayEnd`, you have to make a separate object and put  `workDayStart` and `workDayEnd` there.

Example: 
http://dojo.telerik.com/ewOTo/2